# Why asp:UpdatePanel updates hiddenfield value only on second click on button

Tags: c#, updatepanel, hidden-field

I have problem while updating hiddenfield on button click. When I click on button,
it does not update hiedenfield for **first** time, only if I click button **second** time
then I am getting correct value. I searched on web for this and I could not find solution for this. Does anyone know why it is happening and is it default behaviour or if someone can provide me some other usefull approach to solve this problem.

.aspx file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioQuestion" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="first" Value="first"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="second" Value="second"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateResult" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenResult" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCheck" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" Text="Check"
    CssClass="check"  />
```

Javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.check').click(function () {
            alert($('#hiddenResult').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

.cs file:

```
 protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (radioQuestion.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "first":
            hiddenResult.Value = "YES";
            break;
        case "second":
            hiddenResult.Value = "NO";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you first click the button, what's the value of `$('#hiddenResult').val()`? At first glance it seems that it doesn't have a value and your Javascript is being called before you've assigned a value to it.

Comment: @keyboardP. Well, first time when I click it show nothing. Only when I click for second time it gets value

Comment: What if you do set it like this `<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenResult" runat="server" Value="First Click"/>`. Does "First Click" get shown?

Comment: If I set hiddenfield value, then on first click I am getting setted value, on second click I am getting selected value of radiobuttonlist

Comment: Your `HiddenField` doesn't have a default value assigned to it. When you click the button for the first time, the Javascript code is displaying the value of the HiddenField (which has no value yet) before your server side code has assigned a "YES" or "NO" value. Depending on what you want to do, you can have the server call the next method if the hiddenResult.Value is empty.

Comment: Can you be more specific then you say ** you can have the server call the next method if the hiddenResult.Value is empty**

Comment: What I mean is that in your example you've used `alert('')` to demonstrate that the value isn't being set on first click. Because the Javascript gets executed before the server call, you're going to get the (empty) default value. Therefore, you could have the server check if the hiddenResult value is empty. If it's empty, then have the server refresh the UpdatePanel after setting the value (as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will be helpful for this case is a callback mechanism that is invoked everytime an AJAX request ends . Fortunately, there is one available and it can be registered using:

```
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler).
```

Later, the EndRequestHandler can be implemented for executing any javascript code on request completion. The argument sender can be used to handle specific requests. The following javascript should serve the purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
});
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
   var senderId = sender._activeElement.id;
    if (senderId=="btnCheck") {
        alert($('#<%=hiddenResult.ClientID%>').val());
    }
}
```

**Update:** Just realised that activeElement gets you the element on the form currently in focus, which for this case is not necessarily a good poperty to check for. Below is the updated javascript that takes a better approach by using _postBackSettings:

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
   var senderId = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;
    if (senderId=="btnCheck") {
        alert($('#<%=hiddenResult.ClientID%>').val());
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it in async way. I don't want page to be refreshed

Comment: Updated the answer for handling it in async way. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do. Still you can buy this
1) Trigger is not required for updatepanel with `id=updateResult` as `UpdateMode` is not set and default is always true.
2) You are changing and checking values of `<asp:HiddenFiled>` on with same control.

So what glitches here, your **client side code calls prior to server** it means `alert($('#hiddenResult').val());` is called before setting  `<asp:HiddenFiled>` value at code-behind. Once client code calls by returning true value (True by default in any/your case), request sent to server and your `btnCheck_Click` executes and changes hidden field value with latest one. Next time so on.. You will always get older value with above logic.

> Approach you can use

As I said client side code calls prior to server, So move your server code to client side like

```
   $('.check').click(function () {
        // Get Hidden field
        var hidden = $('[id$=hiddenResult]');

        //Your logic
        if ($('[id$=radioQuestion] input:radio')[0].checked) {
            $(hidden).val('Yes');
        }
        else if ($('[id$=radioQuestion] input:radio')[1].checked) {
            $(hidden).val('No');
        }

        alert($(hidden).val());
  }
```

Don't forget to add [jquery](http://jquery.com/) file for reference at header of your page.

Hope This will help

Comment: I am trying to return selected value when button is clicked and after that display message(it will not be alert, but some modal popup). This code is simplified from my original code. As I've asked in my question, if someone know other approach then this it would be great too. My client required this. If I use it without Updatepanel there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who tried to answer my question helped me a lot. That's why thank you all, but I also have to say that Saurabh answer lead me to find correct solution. I didn't know much about AJAX until now. Back to answer; actually Saurabh was close to find it, only few corrections was necessary to achieve that. Anyway I am posting my working code bellow(only part of Javascript):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    });

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById('btnCheck')) {
            alert($('#<%=hiddenResult.ClientID%>').val());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad it helped. But I must point out a bug in your code. The if block of your code will always execute irrespective of the source of the request because, as long as 'btnCheck' exists, it will always evaluate to true. To understand this better I would like you to try this: create a new asp button and create a trigger for it. Now when you click this new button you will see the alert is still displayed, when it should only be displayed for 'btnCheck'. Please check my updated answer on how to handle this appropriately. The old if logic might not have worked for you but this one should.